# Twitter Bootstrap not working in IE8

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, internet-explorer-8, media-queries

I have tried many solutions from Stack Overflow and looked at the bootstrap documentation and have downloaded local copy of shiv.js and repond.js and included them in footer but after refreshing in IE8 its still same as before no javascript is working and even no media queries are rendering as rendered in google chrome. navbar is also no displaying.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Theme Webmonopolist">
    <meta name="author" content="Faisal Naseer">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/ico/favicon.png">

    <title> WebMonopolist</title>
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/icomoon.css">
    <link href="assets/css/animate-custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,300italic,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>

.......
......

<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/retina.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/smoothscroll.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-func.js"></script>
    <script type=”text/javascript” src=’https://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js’></script>
      <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="assets/js/shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="assets/js/respond.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should put your shiv and respond at the `<head>` tag, like they show [here](http://twbs.github.io/bootstrap/getting-started/#template). It makes it possible detect browser's features before the whole page is loaded.

Second, [here](http://twbs.github.io/bootstrap/getting-started/#respond-file-proto) they say that serving respond.js from file:// pseudo-protocol is disabled for security purposes. Even serving it from a CDN, apparently, won't work, since [here](http://twbs.github.io/bootstrap/getting-started/#respond-js-x-domain) is indicated that for serving from another domain you must make some configuration.

So finally, I fixed all of it, ran the following code **in localhost, not from file://**, and the navbar works like a charm:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/html5shiv/dist/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/respond/dest/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

    <h1>Hello, from IE8!</h1>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```